# Can I have a mail server and use gmail at the same time?

Tags: postfix, gmail, mail-server, imap

I am configuring a mail server (vps)

I installed Postfix and Roundcube, after some hours of configuration I got the connection with MySql and gmail working, the problem is I don't have a user yet so what I want to achieve is to use my own domain name user@example.com and also use gmail as the imap server.

Is it possible or the gmail adress will be reveled? (f.e. realusername@gmail.com)

Comment: No, it's not. The answer is no I can't use gmail without paying, this has nothing to do about the domain registrar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to receive e-mail you have to have a working way of receiving e-mail. This includes a smtp server accepting incoming mail.

If you want to get mail from gmail via IMAP, it has to be sent to your address at gmail.

IMAP is a way for clients to retrieve mail from a server.

Comment: so Dovecot is the way to go, or is there any better alternative?

Comment: Dovecot is an imap server. It's good at that. You still need a smtp server to receive incoming mail.

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading your question correctly, what you want to do is to create a domain on the google servers "@example.com" which lookds to the world like a stand alone server system.

This can be achieved, but it is not an Ubuntu problem or question, and I will mark it so.

I am loath to create a link only answer, but see

https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3453651?hl=en

which details how to get a domain served on the google hardware, how to add e-mail addresses, how to create or redirect web services.

Comment: Only problem with this is GSuite which handles the underlying email parts is not free, so it can get pricey if you aren't careful.

Comment: @ThomasWard Aye, but it is an explicit connection between the domain and google, which is what I believe OP was asking for.  If it were me (IIWM?) I would just create a domain registration somewhere, and create a mail server on my systems, and talk to that mail server.

Comment: +1, or go with Google Suite or whatever registrar's email system is offered as an example.  There's a hundred different ways to do it, I was just making a note that Google Suite is not free :p